# Table variable and error "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create temporary table or variable for ~20 rows.

```
DECLARE @UserDailyStatsForCategories TABLE (
        CategoryId uniqueidentifier not null,
        [Date] date not null,
        [Unique users] int not null,
        [Returning users] int not null,
        [New users] int not null
    );

insert into @UserDailyStatsForCategories (CategoryId, [Date], [Unique users], [Returning users], [New users])                               
     select 
     @CategoryId,
      eventdate,
      count(*),
      count(case when cnt > 1 then 1 end),
      count(case when cnt = 1 then 1 end)
    from
    (
      select cast(eventtime as date) as eventdate, userid, count(*) as cnt
      from telemetrydata
      where [dbo].[TelemetryData].[DiscountId] = @DiscountId
                and [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountClick'
      group by cast(eventtime as date), userid
    ) date_user
    group by eventdate;
```

It works but when I add this:

```
update CategoryDailyStatsTemp 
set
    [CategoryDailyStatsTemp].[Unique users] = @UserDailyStatsForCategories.[Unique users],
    [CategoryDailyStatsTemp].[Returning users] = @UserDailyStatsForCategories.[Returning users],
    [CategoryDailyStatsTemp].[New users] = @UserDailyStatsForCategories.[New users]
where [CategoryDailyStatsTemp].[Id] = @UserDailyStatsForCategories.CategoryId
and [CategoryDailyStatsTemp].[Date] = @UserDailyStatsForCategories.[Date];
```

Then I got error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@UserDailyStatsForCategories".

What is going on?

Comment: `@CategoryID` is a **column** of your declared table `@UserDailyStatsForCategories`. Later you try to use this like you'd use a declared variable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax for this is the following:

```
Update  C
Set     [Unique users]    = U.[Unique users],
        [Returning users] = U.[Returning users],
        [New users]       = U.[New users]
From    CategoryDailyStatsTemp       C
Join    @UserDailyStatsForCategories U   On  U.CategoryId = C.Id
                                         And U.Date = C.Date
```

Comment: Yes if you are going to put the values in a table variable, you then have to join to the table variable to access them in the update query. You also could use a correlated subquery but that is more complicated and slower. Far better to learn the join syntax.